# Side Affix Disappearing On Smaller Views

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hello i dont know how to fix this although ive been trying for days now. Thought i would try asking someone to help as im lost. My right sidebar is nowhere to be seen when i get below sm size

```
<head>


  <style>


  @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

  .affix {
      top: 20px;
  }

  }
  </style>
</head>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-9">   
      {{ page.content }}
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="20">
        {{ page.sidebar_second }}
      </ul>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually the sidebar is there. its just underneath everything. I know you dont like links to sites but maybe easier for me as you wont be able to see it otherwise (not that anyone will help me on here as no one ever does ) sorry im just exaspaerated http://ukfinger.com/comments

Comment: where you want your right sidebar to be in small screen?

Comment: hi Jyoti thanks for the reply. Just after the content Jy. Im starting to wonder if its a drupal thing. Ive added a footer etc but to no avail. i can see the code for the sidebar under the content but it just wont show itself. Ive tried about 50 differant things to sort it to no avail. all ive done all weekend :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .affix {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0; 
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: ah brilliant Jyoti thats has done the job i think. Ill need to look at it more and see how you managed it. Thanks very much.

Comment: mmm i think unrealted there is a wee wobble of width when i start scrolling down. that is unrelated though and ight have to ask another question. I might have some code there somewhere for it as i remember seeing it was a browser problem a few days ago.

Comment: @RegGordon Your welcome, I dont see any "wee wobble" of width on scroll..

Comment: Im getting a small one Jyoti on both Chrome & IE. Its not too bad and after the last 48hrs its quite welcome really. I can live with it for now whilst i get on. This has really held me back. Missed sunday dinner at my mums today because of it. im just thankfull for your help on it.

Comment: @RegGordon I checked on both IE and chrome there is no issue. Sorry to know that you missed the dinner at your mums house. Anyway you will have a good sleep today.. :)